# how to pass a variable to a not() selector?

Tags: jquery-selectors

How do I pass a variable as a class into a not() selector?

I am currently using:

```
var x = "boy";
$("#names").children("." + x).fadeTo(250, 1);
```

to fade a list of names with class "boy", but at the same time I also need to fade out all children of #names that do not have the class contained in var x.

```
$("#names").children(":not()" + "." + x ).fadeTo(250, .5);
```

^Adding the above to the function doesn't give me any errors... but its clearly not working right.  (It works fine if I declare the class (".boy") normally but I need it to work with a variable for other purposes.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#names").children().not("." + x ).fadeTo(250, .5);
```

or

```
$("#names").children(":not(" + "." + x + ")").fadeTo(250, .5);
```

I prefer the first one :)